# Reverse an integer array of length 2^n recursively and return a new array without modifying the original

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion

I encountered the following question in an interview.

Complete this function to return a reversed array without modifying the function signature or the original array. Note that static data types should not be used here at all.

Assume the arrayLength is a power of 2. i.e 2^n. -> I think this is the trick here.

```
int* reverse(int *array, int arrayLength){

}
```

Please help.
Note that I could not really think of a solution to the problem. The interviewer hinted at using 2^n for the puspose, but i could not really think of the solution.

Comment: and... what exactly u did again?

Comment: here is some hard to read code, does it work? `int a = 0,z = arrayLength-1; while(a<z){int tmp=array[a]; array[a--]=array[z],array[z--]=tmp;}`

Comment: thats not recursive @GradyPlayer

Comment: ah dammit what does being recursive help... nothing except crashing the stack on a sufficiently large array...

Comment: sure, but thats the question at hand!  its an interview question after all

Comment: The problem states that the array length is always a power of two. So the recursion's termination condition could be `length == 2`, in which case return a new array with just the two elements swapped. Otherwise, call recursively on both halves of the array, and re-join the results in the inverse order (first half last, second half first).

Comment: @NicolasMiari a power of 2 could be 1 as well (2^0)

Comment: @webNeat You're right, that would be the actual final step. Return copy of  single-element-array.

Comment: Although starting with a one-element array would definitely be an edge case; normally you would start with a higher length, work your way down,  and at some point hit `length == 2` (before `length == 1`).

Comment: @NicolasMiari You are right, going deep to `length == 1` is a waste of time. But should check it as a particular case.

Comment: @webNeat On the other hand, the whole function being recursive is a waste of time.  I wonder if this question is more about following rules such as camel-case variable names than anything else.  Probably best to just going to ```length == 1```

Comment: I don't see any mention of recursion in the interview question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz straight after 2^n  :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas: not sure if the title is actually part of the original question.

Comment: @Grady Player Agree about questionable need to be recursive.  A good recursive answer though would use O(ln2(arrayLength)) stack depth and that shouldn't smash most stacks.

Comment: @chux what the hell is ln2 :) maybe you can implement this in some sort of divide and conquer then blit... but, maybe the point of this interview question is for you to recognize when recursion isn't awesome for every problem...

Comment: @Grady Player  Instead of "ln2", should have used [Binary logarithm or log₂ n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm)  :).

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
int* reverse(int *array, int arrayLength){
  if (arrayLength==1) {
    int* out=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    out[0] = array[0];
    return out;
  }
  int* left = reverse(array+arrayLength/2, arrayLength-arrayLength/2);
  int* right = reverse(array,arrayLength/2);
  int* out = (int*)realloc(left, sizeof(int)*arrayLength);
  memcpy(out+arrayLength/2, right, sizeof(int)*(arrayLength/2));
  free(right);
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int* reverse(int *array, int arrayLength){
    if(arrayLength == 0) return array;
    int* ret = (int*)malloc(arrayLength*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<arrayLength;i++) ret[i] = array[arrayLength-1-i];
    return reverse(ret, 0); // technically recursive
}
```

Comment: Love all the comment-less downvotes on these answers.

Comment: The `memcpy` is not required and the `for-loop` should go all the way to `i<arrayLength`

Answer (score 2):

Agree with OP the the *hint* is "2^n".  As with many recursive functions: divide and conquer.

This routine first deals with errant paramters and the simple lengths. Next, divide the length in half and reverse each half.  Form the result by concatenating the reversed left and right sub-arrays.  First, right, then left.

Usual clean-up follows

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int* reverse(int *array, int arrayLength) {
  // Check parameters
  if (array == NULL || arrayLength < 0) {
    ; // TBD HandleBadParameters();
  }

  // Allocate space for result, not much to do if length <= 1
  int *y = malloc(arrayLength * sizeof *y);
  if (y == NULL) {
    ; // TBD HandleOOM();
  }
  if (arrayLength <= 1) {
    memcpy(y, array, arrayLength * sizeof *y);
    return y;
  }

  // Find reverse of the two halves
  int halflength = arrayLength / 2;
  int *left = reverse(array, halflength);
  int *right = reverse(&array[halflength], halflength);

  // Append them to the result - in reverse order
  memcpy(y, right, halflength * sizeof *y);
  memcpy(&y[halflength], left, halflength * sizeof *y);

  // Clean-up and return
  free(right);
  free(left);
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is (and works):

```
int *reverse(int *array, int arrayLength)
{
    if (arrayLength > 1) {
        int i, n = arrayLength >> 1;
        int *m = calloc(n, sizeof(int));

        memcpy(m, array, n*sizeof(int));
        memcpy(array, array + n, n*sizeof(int));
        memcpy(array + n, m, n*sizeof(int));
        free(m);
        reverse(array, n); 
        reverse(array+n, n); 
    } /* for */
    return array;
} /* reverse */
```

it can be done without temporary storage, but you have to iterate a little.

```
int *reverse(int *a, int al) 
{
    if (al > 1) {
        int i, a1 = al >> 1;

        for (i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i + a1];
            a[i + a1] = temp;
        } /* for */
        reverse(a, a1);
        reverse(a+a1, a1);
    } /* for */
    return a;
} /* reverse */
```

but, it would be nicer just to exchange from the boundaries to the middle and do it completely iterative.

```
int *reverse(int *array, int arrayLength)
{
    int a, b;
    for (a = 0, b = arrayLength-1; a < b; a++, b--) {
        int temp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = temp;
    } /* for */
    return array;
} /* reverse */
```

And just for the ones who asked for a non selfmodifying array, this all-inefficient form:

```
int *reverse(int *array, int arrayLength)
{
    int *a1, *a2;
    int *res;

    if (arrayLength > 1) {
        int l = arrayLength >> 1;
        a1 = reverse(array, l);
        a2 = reverse(array + l, l);
        res = calloc(arrayLength, sizeof(int));
        memcpy(res, a2, l*sizeof(int));
        memcpy(res+l, a1, l*sizeof(int));
        free(a1);
        free(a2);
    } else {
        /* we return always memory alloc'd with malloc() so we have to do this. */
        res = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *res = array[0];
    } /* if */

    return res;

} /* reverse */
```

Comment: In last solution, suggest something like `b = arrayLength-1`.

Comment: ... without modifying the function signature or the **original array**

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I thought on it but forgot to include when writting... Thanks for the point on it!

Comment: without modifying the original array there's a lot of work to be done to get the different arrays concatenated and deleted after being copied.  I'm not interested in doing a so inefficient code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one sneaky way, and it doesn't care what length the array is.  Note: I'm assuming you can't introduce a new function, it has to be done all within the existing function

if the length is postive, it allocates memory and makes a copy, then calls reverse again with a negative length and the copy,  then if the function is called with a negative length, it reverses the first and last inplace, then recursively calls by moving to the next in the array and shrinks the length till there is nothing left to reverse and then the recursive function unwinds

```
int* reverse(int *array, int arrayLength){
        int* result;
        if(arrayLength > 0)
        {
            result =(int*) malloc((sizeof(int)*arrayLength));
            memcpy(result, array, sizeof(int)*arrayLength);
            reverse(result, -arrayLength);
            return result;
        }
        else if(arrayLength < -1)
        {
            int end = (-arrayLength)-1;
            int temp = array[end];
            array[end] = array[0];
            array[0] = temp;
            return reverse(array+1, arrayLength+2);
        }   
        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `arrayLength` is always a power of 2. we will apply the function to the two parts of the array then concat them in the reverse way.
Finaly if the array has only one element, we simply return other array with the same element.

```
int* reverse(int *array, int arrayLength){
    int * newArray = NULL;
    if(arrayLength == 1){
        newArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *newArray = array[0];
    } else if(arrayLength == 2){
        newArray = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        newArray[0] = array[1];
        newArray[1] = array[0];
    } else {
        // apply to first half
        int * first = reverse(array, arrayLength / 2);
        // apply to second half
        int * second = reverse(array + arrayLength / 2, arrayLength / 2);
        // allocate space
        newArray = (int *) malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(int));
        // copy parts in reverse way
        memcpy(newArray, second, arrayLength / 2 * sizeof(int));
        memcpy(newArray + arrayLength / 2, first, arrayLength / 2 * sizeof(int));
        // free allocated space for parts
        free(first);
        free(second);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot.

Knowing that the array is of length 2^n means that it can be safely halved.  We call the function recursively on each half until length is 2.  At this point we swap the two integers.  Think `{ 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7 }`.  When we come back from that, each half is then merged opposite of where it came from ( `{ 4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5}` ).  Rinse and repeat.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * reverse( int* arr, int length )
{

  if ( length == 1 )
  {
    int *result = malloc( sizeof( arr[0] ) );
    result[0] = arr[0];
    return result;
  }

  int * result = 0;

  if ( length == 2 )
  {
    result = malloc( sizeof( arr[0] ) * 2 );
    result[0] = arr[1];
    result[1] = arr[0];
  }
  else
  {
    int half_length = length / 2;

    // named correctly
    int * right = reverse( arr, half_length );
    int * left  = reverse( arr + half_length, half_length );

    result = malloc( sizeof( arr[0] ) * length );

    for ( int i = 0; i < half_length; ++i )
    {
      result[i] = left[i];
      result[ i + half_length ] = right[i];
    }

    free( right );
    free( left );
  }

  return result;

}

int main( void )
{
  int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
  int length = 8;

  int *reversed = reverse( arr, length );

  for ( int i = 0; i < length; ++i )
  {
    printf( "%d %d\n", arr[i], reversed[i] );
  }

  free( reversed );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You too forgot to consider the edge case of `length == 1` (see my comments above and @webNeat's).

Comment: I put it as an edge case because it will half the amount of recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

for all integer arrays with more than 2 elements.
The basic idea is to swap elements from both ends untill the number of elements remaining is 1.

int* reverse_array(int* array, int arrayLength)
{

```
if(arrayLength <2)
{
    return NULL;
}
else
{
     int *array1 = NULL;
     int *array2 = NULL;
     array1 = malloc(arrayLength*sizeof(int));
     memcpy(array1,array,arrayLength*sizeof(int));

     /*swap the start and end*/
     swap(array1,(array1+arrayLength-1));

      /* swap the next pair */
     array2 = reverse_array(array1+1,arrayLength-2);
     memcpy(array1+1,array2,(arrayLength-2)*sizeof(int));

     if(array2!= NULL)
     {
        free(array2);
     }
     return array1;
}
```

}